# Show filter parameter in Jasper Report?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I have a jasper report with parameters(names and date) and want to the following on my report.

Filter by : Name - Stevie
            Date - 20/4/1909

How do I NOT show if the user never filters by Name but date? Im pretty new to Jasper report and hope someone can enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: You want to know that you will show both parameter if date has some value. It does not matter that name is coming or not. Am I right?

Comment: @user1791574 yes, if user enters both parameters, i want both to show and if none is entered, none will be shown. How do i go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for all text field and static text. You need to add xml for printWhenExpression value and put there your value, on base of that you can show hide your text field.

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement x="210" y="3" width="160" height="15" uuid="8e21ca6a-7eb9-4deb-8b36-9df9db27314c">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[($F{your condition will be here})]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{your text field value}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```